# Generate Short Random Uniquer Promotional Codes

Tags: c#, sql

On a C# application I need to create UNIQUE Promotional codes.

The promotional codes will be store in a SQL Table (SQL Server 2012).

Initially I though of GUIDS but they are to long to give to users.

I am considering a 6 alphanumeric code resulting in 52 521 875 unique combinations.

**What do you think?**

But how to generate the code so it is UNIQUE? I am considering:

1. Use random;
2. Use ticks of current datetime
3. Pre generate all codes in the database and pick it randomly ...
   This approach has the problem of occupying two much space.

What would be a good approach to generate the random unique code?

**UPDATE 1**

For the approach in 1 I came up with the following C# code:

```
  Random random = new Random();

  Int32 count = 20;
  Int32 length = 5;

  List<String> codes = new List<String>();

  Char[] keys = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".ToCharArray();

  while (codes.Count < count) {

    var code = Enumerable.Range(1, length)
      .Select(k => keys[random.Next(0, keys.Length - 1)])  // Generate random char
      .Aggregate("", (e, c) => e + c); // Join into a string              

    codes.Add(code);

  }
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
  String source = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

  while (codes.Count < count) {

    length = 5;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(5);

    while (length-- > 0)
      builder.Append(source[random.Next(source.Length)]);

    codes.Add(builder.ToString());

  }
```

Which approach do you think is faster?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: How many codes will you generate?

Comment: Can you just use sequential codes? `00000`, `000001`, ... , `00000Z`, ... , `ZZZZZZ`.

Comment: I am not sure yet how many I will need but from project to project I would only need to vary the lenght of the codes. And of course by using uppercase and lowercasE I can easily increase the number of codes.

Comment: For example, Google Maps use for short links uppercase and lowercase letters with numbers and a lenght of 5 ... So that would be more then enough for me

Comment: Sequential codes is a bad idea. Sometimes you offer 40 codes to the same entity ... They could guess and try the next ones ...

Answer (score 5):

Eric Lippert showed how to use a [multiplicative inverse](http://ericlippert.com/2013/11/14/a-practical-use-of-multiplicative-inverses/) to obfuscate sequential keys. Basically, the idea is to generate sequential keys (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.) and then obfuscate them.

I showed a more convoluted way to do it in my article series [Obfuscating Sequential Keys](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=839).

The beauty of this approach is that the keys appear random, but all you have to keep track of is a single number: the next sequential value to be generated.

YouTube uses a similar technique to generate their video IDs.

Comment: Really interesting ... Any limit for the size of the int? This could be used to generate a KEY in a SQL database having as base the PK which is an int, correct? In the urls, as your example state, there might be a problem ... Sometimes it is nice to have only lowercase characters ... but that is just a detail.

Comment: Is it possible to use your code but using different bases? For example, a base with only lower case letters?

Comment: @MDMoura: Yes, it's possible. There are two parts to my obfuscation technique: mapping the number, and then encoding. You can encode using whatever combination of characters you like. There's no real limit on the size of the number, although practical considerations would probably limit you to 64 bits. But nothing stops you from using BigInteger if you want. In truth, you'd probably want to use the multiplicative inverse (Eric Lippert's blog post) for the mapping, and then do the encoding.

Comment: Do you know any C# implementation of it? I was looking for obfuscate Ints to Lowercase characters base with equal length ... The idea is to use this not only in promotional codes generation but also to obfuscate IDs included in URLs

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry about generating a unique code. Instead . . .

- Generate a random code.
- Insert that code into a database. It belongs in a column that has a unique index.
- Trap the error that results from trying to insert a duplicate value.
- If you *get* a duplicate value error, generate another random code, and try again.

Comment: That is that I am considering ... But for, let's say, 400 000 codes I should have much more combinations so what you mention does not happen often ... I don't even need to try to insert it ... I can try to find it to check if exists ... Or is it faster to try to insert it and catch the error from the unique index?

Comment: Taking 6 values from a pool of 36 gives you about 1.4 billion permutations. Taking 6 from a pool of 62 (using both upper- and lowercase letters) gives you about 44 billion permutations. Taking 7 from a pool of 62 gives you about 2.5E12 permutations.

Comment: It's generally better to insert and trap the error--good values require only one round-trip to the database. And you *must* trap errors anyway.

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: Is it possible to insert 20 records with one SQL command and get the errors and in which one the errors occurred?

Comment: There are several different ways to get bulk data into a database, but 20 isn't bulk data. For 20, I'd just insert them one at a time. 20 thousand is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for number 1.
Number 2 is not that random (you have lower and upper limit), number 3 is an overkill.

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
DECLARE @VALUES varchar(100)
SET @VALUES = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'


SELECT SUBSTRING(@Values, CAST(FLOOR(RAND()*LEN(@Values)) + 1 AS int), 1) + 
       SUBSTRING(@Values, CAST(FLOOR(RAND()*LEN(@Values)) + 1 AS int), 1) + 
       SUBSTRING(@Values, CAST(FLOOR(RAND()*LEN(@Values)) + 1 AS int), 1) + 
       SUBSTRING(@Values, CAST(FLOOR(RAND()*LEN(@Values)) + 1 AS int), 1) + 
       SUBSTRING(@Values, CAST(FLOOR(RAND()*LEN(@Values)) + 1 AS int), 1) + 
       SUBSTRING(@Values, CAST(FLOOR(RAND()*LEN(@Values)) + 1 AS int), 1)
```

Use a table for storing previously generated codes to check for uniqeness.

Comment: `But how to generate the code so it is UNIQUE?` So you say it will generate *unique* values with `RAND()?`